# Building a BSON filter from raw query string

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

Is it possible to create a collection filter from a raw query string? If so, how?

I'm using the `mongocxx` driver and want to use some tested queries from the mongo shell instead of building them inconveniently with that `BSONCXX` streambuilder. But I can not find any examples.

I tried to convert `from_json()`, but this throws an error

```
bsoncxx::from_json("{ \"val\": { $gt: 0, $lt: 9 }}");
Got parse error at "$", position 11: "SPECIAL_EXPECTED": could not parse JSON document
```

whereby

```
bsoncxx::from_json("{ \"val\": { \"$gt\": 0, \"$lt\": 9}}");
```

is leading to an unrecoverable exception and crashes the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually

```
bsoncxx::from_json("{ \"val\": { \"$gt\": 0, \"$lt\": 9}}");
```

was not the issue. The transformation from `std::string` to `bsoncxx::view` was. Not 100% sure where the reason for the crash was, but this does the trick for me.

Solution:

```
std::string query( R"( { "val": { "$gt": 0, "$lt": 9}} )");
collection.find(bsoncxx::from_json(query.c_str()).view());
```